# Content cropped when browser's zoom changes

Tags: css, google-chrome, zooming, ems

When I zoom out on Chrome, the content of my website gets cropped off. Here is a screen shot of what I mean.

[image]

I can't find a solution to this. Is there even one? I read about changing sizes to ems and tried that but that didn't fix it. Hope someone can help.

This is the link I'm talking about but there are more pages with the same issue http://wardrobeicons.com/the-icons-update/elle-ferguson-perfect-wardrobe-5/

Comment: Please post your html/css code.

Comment: It would be too much code since I don't really know where the issue is coming from, from which element I mean. This is the link I'm talking about http://wardrobeicons.com/the-icons-update/elle-ferguson-perfect-wardrobe-5/. Looks ok when zooming out in Firefox but it doesn't in Chrome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is this part that causes the crop I think.

```
#content.weekly-update #magazine {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 580px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

As a quick fix you can increase the `height` value too `600px` or more.

Or drop the floating layout, use CSS table layout instead for example - it has one of the greatest features of equal height on the cells.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Removing the 'overflow:auto' did not work. How would I drop the floating layout? Does it mean changing the current floated structure into a css table structure?

Comment: Yeah, css table structure is recommended for this case, as you want the left and right columns to have equal height.

Comment: That would take quite a while since there are 16 page templates... I'll change the height to 600px for the time being and will mark your answer the correct one. Thank you for your help Pangloss

Comment: I also noticed the big image is set as background of `#trends .trend` and it requires to have a height to be set. Again, css table or flex layout would be a proper fix for it, otherwise you can use javascripts.